# run sfc /scannow as administrator, but I am administrator

Tags: windows-server-2003, permissions, runas

On my windows 2003 I have to run **sfc /scannow** as admin. I have tried to run it as local administrator and domain administrator, but it says I need of administrator privilege ????

I have tried **runas /user:administrator cmd** and then on a new shell **sfc /scannow**. But it does not work too.

The error message is:

> You must be an administrator running a console session in order to use the Windows File Checker utility.

the error message is in italian and should be translated in english as above.
The following is the cmd's screenshot of the error. I am connected as domain administrator but I run it a runas to be local admin.

[image: cmd with administrator privilege on rdp]

Comment: You talk about error messages...what are they?  It would help if we see the error verbatim and whether you are at the server or RDP'd into it.

Comment: The message from Windows 2003 is not very clear. It talks about "console" -> "You must be an administrator running a console session in order to use the Windows File Checker utility." which at first sight I was taking for a "console window" but it's actually /Console switch as per my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to choose `Run as` on `CMD` and type in login and password of Administrator. Then you can run the command. You need to be logged in `RDP` in `CONSOLE` mode (`/console` or `/admin` switch depending on RDP version). Then it will work.

[image]

Comment: It worked for me. Followed the below command in RUN window. **"mstsc /console /admin"** login to your server/Desktop system remotly. Then do **"CMD"** run as admin. Now you will not see and issue and will get all option on running **"SFC"**